# Flexslider fade animation works; slide does not

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider

I am using [flexslider](https://github.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider) to rotate text across my hero image on my home page.

Using `animation:"fade"` everything works great. However, when I set the `animation` to `slide`, nothing ever shows.

Looking at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691711/flexslider-fades-but-will-not-slide) about the same issue, I've added `position:relative` to my `li` elements, but still no luck.

**CSS**

```
#slider {
    z-index: 10;
    text-align: center;
    height: 550px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 50px;

    .slide {
        position: relative;
    }
}

.flexslider {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
}
```

**jquery**

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    'animation': 'slide',
    'directionNav': false,
    'controlNav': false
});
```

One thing I have noticed when I inspect the element, I am seeing a width of `0px` getting applied by flexslider.

```
<li class="slide flex-active-slide" data-thumb-alt="" style="width: 0px; margin-right: 0px; float: left; display: block;">...</li>
```

I'm not sure what I've done so that this works:

```
// 'animation': 'slide',
   'directionNav': false,
   'controlNav': false
```

And this does not:

```
'animation': 'slide',
'directionNav': false,
'controlNav': false
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: There's a comma missing in the jQuery. It should read 'animation': 'slide',

Comment: I noticed that but forgot to update - even when that is correct, it is failing to render.